android TUS upload files to server
Im trying to use TUS to upload file to server. im getting error
"unexpected status code 302 while resuming upload" 

and have times i receives another error
"unexpected status code (302) while uploading chunk". 

My server is listening to uncoming files. What wrong? Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. What files are you uploading? What is your upload process? Are there any relevant configurations?

In my case i got 302 error means is redirecting.
I forgot also to add headers to my request and i receive from response an new location and need to make a new call with new location.
Now its working
